# Mocking Window with Sinon, Mocha, Enzyme, and React

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to mock out the window object for a component I'm using with just the four libraries listed above.

I know it can be done with JSDom but the client is against using it. Based on my research simply doing sinon.stub(window,'location') should work but when I run my tests I still get Window undefined in my component.

Currently the component is called within the render return {window.location.host}

any thoughts to what I am doing wrong to get sinon to stub out that one piece. Once I stub out that piece then I can focus on testing the other parts of that component that have nothing to do with window.

My Test Method:

```
import React from 'react';

import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import chai from 'chai';
chai.should();
import sinon from 'sinon';

import BillingStatementRow from '../BillingStatementRow';

describe('Test <BillingStatementRow /> Component', function() {

    context('Function Testing', function() {

        it('Test - onFieldChange - Make sure it handles NaN', function() {

            var e = {target: {value: NaN}};

            var window = { location : { host : "..." } };

            var mockedOnChange = sinon.spy();

            const wrapper = shallow (
                <BillingStatementRow slds={''} key={'1'}
                    Id={'1'} inputValue={'0'} salesInvoice={'SIN0001'}
                    invoicedAmount={1000} duedate={'1461628800000'}
                    outstandingBalance={1000} receiptRemaining={1000}
                    amountAllocated={1000} onChange={mockedOnChange.bind(this,'BS0001')} />
            );

            wrapper.instance().onFieldChange('amountAllocated', e);
            wrapper.update();


        })


    });

});
```

Comment: I assume that you have declared `window` first (as an empty object or something)? Also, is it available everywhere (i.e. is it a global)? **EDIT**: hmm never mind, `window.location` isn't a function anyway, and Sinon can only stub functions. Still, what exactly do you want to test? Why not just declare a global `window = { location : { host : "..." } }`?

Comment: Yep window is declared first yet it still gives me window is not defined.

Comment: Try `global.window = { location : ... }` instead.

Comment: Thank you - it looks like it worked.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sinon stubs/spies/mocks only work with functions. In this case, you're trying to mock a global (nested) variable, for which Sinon isn't the right tool.

Instead, just like in a browser, you can create a global object that mocks just the right amount of `window` to work with your component, which is easy because it only accesses `window.location.host`.

So before instantiating the component, declare the following:

```
global.window = { location : { host : 'example.com' } };
```

Comment: Getting this warning [ts] Cannot find name 'global'. Can you please help me here